# Photoshop: create realistic text on paper?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers, photoshop-effects

How can I make a realistic text on paper just like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

I first remove that text, and place mine, but that text doesn't appear as the original, doesn't seem realistic:

[image]

The difficult part is how to make these soft gradient and the very small grains on the edge, and toning between the shadows and the text color. Any idea how to accomplish the look seen in my first picture?

Comment: Your perspective for the text seems off. Also try blurring is slightly and make it not so black and use multiply mode.

Answer (score 5):

Try reducing the opacity to 90-95%, apply bit of blur to make the edges less sharp, a bit of noise to introduce some grain and make the fills less flat.

Also by editing the Layer style (right click your text layer and choose the first option) you can apply a Gradient Overlay, which (if done properly) can also add some realistic shading with the right settings.

Comment: Assuming a relatively recent version of Photoshop is being used nothing you've said requires rasterizing text. Use Smart Filters.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't aware, i've just removed that part :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

[image]

Own text has a random font, but a solid black color. It was at first distorted by warping to simulate lens barrel distortion (=curved line) Then it was skewed to simulate a tilted watching direction.

A copy was made just below. The copy is in layer "Bad text", It has following quality downgradings:

- gaussian blur
- dark magenta color (Image > adjustments > Hue&Saturation > colorize)
- added monochrome noise

The solid text is made a half transparent. Here's a closer look:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]Try using a displacement map to emulate the surface texture on the font -- an in progress frame above of something I'm working on.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding noise in photoshop? That helps a lot. I would also try giving it some blur. The perspective is also different from your reference photo but without seeing the reference photo I don't think I would have noticed

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Actually there's nearly all essential. Only a receipelike format is off. Still +1.